# Automatic cut off after switch is pressed

Tags: switches, design

I have a fun one for you. Here is my diagram:

[image: Texas Instruments_LMC555_monostable]

It's a 555 timer in a monostable one shot configuration. What I want to do is find a way to prevent the LED from staying on if the switch is held down. So whether the switch is just pressed or held down, I want the LED to stay lit the same amount of time and then shut off.

I was trying to find an auto shut off switch, but I didn't really have luck with one.

Comment: IIRC, you're going to need a completely different arrangement for that.

Comment: Such as? I don't understand. This isn't the way it's going on the board. Thanks!

Comment: Feed the switch though a capacitor so it creates a pulse instead of a constant low value?

Comment: It just leaves the light on, kind of reversing what the switch is supposed to do

Answer (score 4):

That's simple — you just need to AC-couple the switch, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBDdJt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R4 and C4 are new components; their time constant is set to 10 ms, a small fraction of your timer period. Regardless of how long the switch is held, the `TRIGGER` input of the 555 will only see a short low-going pulse.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because the LED just stays lit now whether the button is pressed or not.

Here's an example

![Circuit Example](http://postimg.org/image/fos6nccu1/).

Comment: You forgot the additional resistor.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. I forgot to save my renumbered project, so my numbers were different from yours. But the 100nF wasn't producing anything, so I upped it and voila! Thank you, Dave :)